# In HighCharts how to set number of xAxis autoly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

As you can see , I'm using HighStock of HighCharts now in order to have scroll bar.
I want to set max number of xAxis. It works if I code like this:

```
xAxis: {
    max: 8
    categories: data.categories
}
```

Here is the rendering: 
[image: normal one]　
But when it concern to some data that hasn't so many xAxis data , it will show like this :
[image: Bad one]
What I want to realize is that when the data is less than a certain number,for example, 8, It will occupy the chart instead of leaving so many blank.
Here is the pic:
[image: My target]

Comment: Please test the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/x8azpjcw/ which checks if categories array is bigger than 8, if not then set maxium value as categoires length.

Comment: @SebastianBochan It works ! Thx. It seems a good solution. May be HighCharts hasn't a simple option to set this. If you Answer on below I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is check if categories array is bigger than 8, if not then set maximum value as categories length

```
xAxis: {
        max: categories.length < 8 ? categories.length - 1: 8,
        categories: categories
    },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/x8azpjcw